# Bash regexp .* matches too far

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file input.txt with the following content:

```
foo
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3")]
bar")]
quux
```

To match the `1.2.3` from the input the following script is used:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
fileContent=$(cat input.txt)
[[ "$fileContent" =~ $regex ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

I would expect the output to be `1.2.3` but it is:

```
1.2.3")]
bar
```

Why is that so? How to fix it?

The regular expressions tester at https://regex101.com works as expected.

Comment: Greediness. Try `'\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([^()]*)"\)\]'`.

Comment: @stribizhev Wow, nice, works indeed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` is called a greedy dot matching subpattern and it matches `"`, and `)`, any character [including a newline](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html#FTN.AEN17189).

Thus, the best trick to limit the greediness is using a negated character class `[^"]` that will match any character but `"` (if there can be no quotes inside the quoted string):

```
'\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([^"]*)"\)\]'
                                ^^^^^
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/sZ82Kj)

or - if there should be no `(` and `)` inside the quoted string:

```
'\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([^()]*)"\)\]'
                                ^^^^^
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/gjimCL)

Comment: Actually, both the solutions here assume there are just spaces, basic punctuation and word characters inside the quoted string. If there can be escaped entities, the regex will be a bit more complicated: [`'\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([^\\"]*(\\.[^\\"]*)*)"\)\]'`](http://ideone.com/luGBKQ).

Comment: Actually, the `.` *does* match a newline; that's how the greediness of the `*` causes a problem.

Comment: @chepner: True, I typed that automatically without thinking. [*In those cases where there is a newline in a multiple line expression, the dot will match the newline.*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html#FTN.AEN17189)

Comment: Those links are irrelevant to the regular expressions used by `bash`. `bash` itself doesn't define its regular expression format; it uses the local implementation of `regex(3)`. (See `man 7 re_format` for details.)

Comment: That help does not specifically state that a dot can match a newline, it just says *`.` (matching any single character)*.